# Hide app content when overview button clicked

Tags: android, security, background, tasklist

I would like to be able to hide the content of the app when it is not in foreground, for example, when I click the overview button(task list), the Chase banking app would just show pure solid color and hide all the content. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image: Example of what I want to achieve, show blank instead of a snapshot of the app]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the answer should be add the following in onCreate of activity. This also block user from taking screen shots of the activity.

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);`

Answer (score 0):

You can override onStop method in an activity and make the view invisible.